# operating system not found

Tags: windows-7, windows

I reformatted and deleted partitions in my hard drive using mini tool partition wizard but before I formatted it runs in three Windows,XP Vista and 7, then I try to install Windows again and  operating system not found, I want to install again  Windows 7, or Ubuntu later if possible, we have 2 PCs with the same brand and model here, I try to put the other hard drive and it works very well, it means the problem is in my hard drive which I reformatted, *which is the easiest way to to solve OS not found?*

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any driver disks with your PCs? Did you try to add SATA driver manually?

Since you have 2 identical PCs, you always can clone hard drive of healthy machine. But make sure that cloning direction is right: I am always confused with Norton Ghost dialogues which one is source which - destination...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve "OS not found" is to install an OS.

The not so easy way is to install a bootloader (GRUB works well), and point it to the OS's you cannot find.

Comment: i try to installed windows 7 but it did not works, but still no operating system found